# How to list content of field in bash

Tags: bash, list, printing, field

How to list content of  field  in bash . 
My field looks like  : array=('+47177372141 '+41753459833'  )

```
 for ((i=0;i<$pn;i++)); do  echo ${pn[${i}]}  done
```

The problem is that I get amount:2 
 not the  content of the field.

So I want to fix this code to receive : 
+47177372141 
+41753459833

Comment: Your question is unclear. You create an array called `array` but then attempt to echo data out of an array called `pn`. Which is correct or are these supposed to be different (and how do they relate)? What is "amount:2" and what is "the content" of the field? Your array assignment also has a syntax problem. It looks like you're missing a closing `'` before the space. What do you mean "receive"? Do you want one line of output reading `+47177372141 +41753459833`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that you want your output to look exactly like

```
+47177372141 +41753459833
```

and you are storing your data in an array like this

```
pn=('+47177372141' '+41753459833')
```

Then the answer is

```
echo "${pn[@]}"
```

If you meant something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array named `array` and a variable `pn` holding the number of elements in `array`:

```
$ array=('+47177372141' '+41753459833' )
$ pn=2
$ for ((i=0;i<$pn;i++)); do  echo ${array[$i]}; done
+47177372141
+41753459833
```

Another way to iterate over an array (be it numerically indexed or associative) is:

```
$ for key in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$key: ${array[$key]}"; done
0: +47177372141
1: +41753459833
```